# Tableview cell not being clicked when using dispatch mechanism

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa, ipad

I am trying to utilize dispatch mechanism to get the contents on background, and update the tableview once gets it, however, such mechanism works, but once reloading, the tableviewcell is unclickable. When I remove [self._tableView reloadData], it is being clickable. Below is my code. Any suggestions?

```
NSString *const cellIdentifier = @"AutoFill";    
    UITableViewCell *cell = [_tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);

dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    NSString *te = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSArray *a = [te componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];

    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        [self._tableView reloadData];
    });
});


return cell;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to access that array in the background - you are just adding complexity for the sake of adding complexity, which is never useful.

```
- The tableView loads it's data and asks the dataSource for a row
- You create a row but then ask the table to reload
- The tableView loads it's data and asks the dataSource for a row
- You create a row but then ask the table to reload
- The tableView loads it's data and asks the dataSource for a row
- You create a row but then ask the table to reload
- The tableView loads it's data and asks the dataSource for a row
- You create a row but then ask the table to reload
```

I think you get the point...

You should not be calling `reloadData` when you provide a row it will be displayed in the tableView

**Note** if you did the normal thing and didn't fetch the data in the background this would not even be an issue you had to worry about

### Update

Your code accesses an array in the background - does nothing useful with it and then calls back to the main thread to set a property that is not even determined by the result of the work in the background thread. What are you actually trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

You're stuck in an infinite loop. When you call `reloadData` it forces the table to reload which then calls:

```
- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

and you start all over again. You should be updating the cell, not the table. Try `[cell setNeedsLayout];` or `[cell.contentView setNeedsLayout];`